Getting error while fetching the user mail in alexa using python
I have created a smart home alexa skill using aws lamdba. Given all the permission required to access the information of the user. Still not able to resolve the Access Denied issue.
Trying to access user email using the below code in python:
def user_email(access_token):
    try:
        # API endpoint URL
        url="https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v2/accounts/~current
        /settings/Profile.email"
        #url="https://api.amazonalexa.com/v2/accounts/~current
        /settings/Profile.email"
        headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
        }
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            email = response.json().get("email")
            return email
        else:
            print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
            return None
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

Getting the below error in response to above code:
response:
Error: 403 - 
{
    "code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
    "message": "Consent token in request does not have access to resource requested"
}

I changed the scope from profile to alexa::profile:email:read and added custom model using which I have enable the user consent to send their email address.
